# PowerShell: Loading MySql.Data.dll in MacOS - Could not load file or Assembly

Tags: powershell, mysql-connector

I am trying to load the `MySql.Data.dll` on MacOS and I am greeted with the following error:

```
Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly '/[FILE_PATH]/MySql.Data.dll'. The system cannot find the file specified. "
```

Test.ps1:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("./MySql.Data.dll")
```

I downloaded the connector from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ and selected .NET & Mono as the Operating system.

On a Windows machine the following works (connector was installed)

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.25\Assemblies\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.dll")
```

Im struggling to find much documentation on this so im not really sure if it is supported for MacOS.

TIA

Comment: Try full path to file instead of `"./MySql.Data.dll"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the fix for me:

```
Add-Type -Path "./MySql.Data.dll"
```